# Select options disappear in end of card

Tags: c#, html, css, razor

[image: this is how it looks]

I tried z-index and overflow in a lot of ways but they didn't work 
this is my select

```
<div class="col-md-9" >
                                                            <select id="category-detail1" multiple="multiple" >
                                                                @for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.CategoryDetailPeymankar.Count; i++)
                                                                {
                                                                    string sel = "";
                                                                    string[] arr = new string[0];
                                                                    if (ViewBag.CategoryDetail != null && ViewBag.CategoryDetail.Length > 0)
                                                                    {
                                                                        arr = ViewBag.CategoryDetail.Split(',');
                                                                    }
                                                                    foreach (var item in arr)
                                                                    {
                                                                        if (int.Parse(item) == ViewBag.CategoryDetailPeymankar[i].Id)
                                                                        {
                                                                            sel = "selected";
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                    <option @sel value="@ViewBag.CategoryDetailPeymankar[i].Id">@ViewBag.CategoryDetailPeymankar[i].Title</option>
                                                                }
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>
```

how i can see all of my options of select list without disappearing behind of card 
I dont want to scroll , i want show options in top of card

Comment: Give the div which holds your options z-index that is like 10000 so that div must stand out if you layed your page properly.

Comment: @MirkoAcimovic it didn't work , i tried z-index in a lot of ways but not working